# Border image not showing

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to have a customized image as the border but it's not showing. I was sure that the id I'm using is correct, because when I tried `border-style:solid;` the black lined border was showing.

```
#panel-902-1-0-1 {
    border-width: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-image: url(bg-trailed.png) repeat;
}
```

The image is in the same folder with the css file.

Comment: Can you include this as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: completely revised.. I just realised I misunderstood your question completely. You are trying to use a border-image.

border-image-source: If the value is ‘none’ or if the image cannot be displayed (or the property doesn't apply), the border styles will be used; otherwise the element's ‘border-style’ borders are not drawn and the border image is drawn as described in the sections below.

Looks like you may have hit this one, as suggested above, a fiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to slice the image:

```
#panel-902-1-0-1 {
    border-width: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-image: url(bg-trailed.png) 25% repeat;
}
```